# get offsetTop on SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg

Why is `offsetTop` returning `undefined` on this SVG element?

```js
var svg = document.querySelector('svg')
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1')

console.log('svg', svg.offsetTop)
console.log('h1', h1.offsetTop)
```

```html
<svg width="26" height="30" viewBox="0 0 12 14">
  <path d="M6 4.038L12 0v3.623L6 8 0 3.623V0l6 4.038zm0 6L12 6v3.623L6 14 0 9.623V6l6 4.038z"/>
</svg>
    
<h1>This works</h1>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The inheritance tree for DOM elements has Element as a base class with SVGElement and HTMLElement deriving separately from that. [offsetTop is defined on the HTMLElement interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#extensions-to-the-htmlelement-interface) and not on the Element interface so SVG elements don't support it.

You could get this information by calling [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) instead. This would work for all elements.

Comment: Is there a work around to get this information on an SVG element?

Comment: `element.offsetTop` and `element.getBoundingClientRect().top` are not equivalent. The former is relative to the document, while the latter is relative to the top of the client. ie, offsetTop will usually not return a negative value, while the other often will.

Comment: @AJFarkas according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop , the former is relative to the parent.  So to get its equivalent using getBoundingClientRect(), you'd call getBoundingClientRect() on both the element and its parent, and subtract.